# Android change marker title dynamically

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My target is to change marker title on button click. The problem is that I cannot get marker and set title of it in `onCreate()` because it is initialized in `onMapReady()`. I have the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateMarkerTexts(marker, "ss", "gg");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    enableMyLocation();
    onMyLocationButtonClick();

    final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(51.2001, 62.9187))
                .title("Some title")
                .snippet(getResources().getString(R.string.somestr))));


    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  //some params
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        getInfoWindow(marker);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save your marker instance in your class instead of saving it in your onMapReady scope :

```
Marker marker;

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ...
    marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(51.2001, 62.9187))
            .title("Some title")
            .snippet(getResources().getString(R.string.somestr))));
```

Comment: Sir, you are genious!